# Optimization on a set of data using python

Tags: python, optimization

Optimization on a set of data using python.

Following data sets available
x, y, f(x), f(y).

Function to be optimized (maximize): 
f(x,y) = f(x)*y - f(y)*x

based on following contraints:

V >= sqrt(f(x)^2+f(y)^2)

I >= sqrt(x^2+y2)

where V and I are constants.

Can anyone please let me know what optimization module do I need to use? From what I understand I need to perform a discrete optimization as I have set f values for x, y, f(x) and f(y).

Comment: check scipy documentation http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html

Comment: Also, f(x, y) and f(x) are the same function?

Comment: No they are different

Answer (score 1):

Using complex optimizers (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) for such a problem is rather a bad idea.

It looks like a problem which can be quite easily solved in under `O(n^2)` where `n=max(|x|,|y|)`, simply:

1. sort `x,y,f(x),f(y)` creating `sorted(x), sorted(y), sorted(f(x)), sorted(f(y))`
2. for each `x` find the positions in `sorted(y)` for which `I^2 >= x^2+y^2` holds and similarly for `f(x)` and `sorted(f(y))` and `V^2 >= f(x)^2 + f(y)^2` (two binary searches, as `I^2 >= x^2+y^2 <=> |y| <= sqrt(I^2-x^2)` so you can find the "barrier"in constant time and then use bin searches to find actual data points which are the closest ones "on the right side of inequality")
3. Iterate through `sorted(x)` and for each `x`:

   - Iterate simultanously through elements of `y` and `f(y)` and discard (in this loop) points which are not in borth intervals found in step 2. (linear complexity)
   - Record argument pairs `x_max,y_max` for which `f(x_max,y_max)` is maximized
4. Return `x_max,y_max`

Total complexity is under quadratic, as step 1 takes `O(nlgn)`, each iteration of loop in step 2 is `O(lgn)` so the whole step 2 takes `O(nlgn)`, loop in step 3 is `O(n)` and loop in first substep of step 3 is `O(n)` (but in real life it should be almost constant due to the constraints), which makes the whole algorithm `O(n^2)` (and in most cases it will behave as `O(nlgn)`). It also does not depend on the definition of `f(x,y)` (it uses it as a black box) so you can optimize an arbitrary function is such a way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a beginner in this field. I do understand the gist of what you are saying. But have very faint idea as how to apply it.

Comment: Can you please verify something for me? What is the Step one doing. as in what are we doing with the sort function?

Comment: Step 1 is supposed to sort all elements of this sets (as these are just real numbesr) in order to be able to perform efficiently other steps (like binary search etc.)